# Increment attribute with Arel table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I want to increment a value with arel_table
I try this

```
update_manager = Arel::UpdateManager.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
i = Arel::Table.new(:items)
update_manager.table(i)
update_manager.where(i[:id].not_eq(id)).
   set [ [ i[:order], i[:order] + 1 ] ]
```

but update_manager.to_sql return this :

```
"UPDATE \"items\" SET \"order\" = NULL"
```

How can I do ?

---

with

```
set [ [ i[:order], i[:order] ] ]
```

I got

```
"UPDATE \"items\" SET \"order\" = \"items\".\"order\""
```

with

```
set [ [ i[:order], 1 ] ]
```

I got

```
"UPDATE \"items\" SET \"order\" = 1 "
```

Comment: If you just want to increment a value you can do in SQL with `UPDATE bars SET foo = foo + 1`. So something like `set [ [ i[:order], "order + 1"   ] ]`

Comment: This is much better since you don't need to know the value on the application side.

Comment: Thank you!
but `[ [ i[:order], "order + 1" ] ]` send `order = 0` 
I have many where statement, so I prefer Arel as sql statement `where a = ? and b=? and c=? ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
Item.where.not(id: id).where(a: a, b: b, c: c).update_all('order = order + 1')
```

As for Arel:

```
i[:items] + 1
# => #<Arel::Nodes::Grouping:0x000000074152d8 @expr=#<Arel::Nodes::Addition:0x00000007415300 @left=#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#<Arel::Table:0x000000074805b0 @name="items", @engine=ActiveRecord::Base, @columns=nil, @aliases=[], @table_alias=nil, @primary_key=nil>, name=:items>, @right=1, @operator=:+>>
```

it looks like a reasonable `Arel::Nodes::Grouping`, also

```
(i[:items] + 1).to_sql
# => "(\"items\".\"items\" + 1)"
```

So the fact that

```
set [ [ i[:order], i[:order] + 1 ] ]
```

results in

```
SET \"order\" = NULL
```

looks more like a bug in Arel.

FYI if you pass the result of `(i[:items] + 1).to_sql` to the update manager

```
update_manager.set [ [ i[:order], (i[:order] + 1).to_sql ] ]
```

then it will be passed to SQL query as a string value to be assigned, not as an expression (makes sense):

```
UPDATE \"items\" SET \"order\" = '(\"items\".\"order\" + 1)'
```

so you would need to write some additional processing (e.g. get resulting sql string, cut off those quotes, execute resulting sql). But personally I would go with `ActiveRecord` instead of `Arel`.

Also you may want to take a look at [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem.